# Running Cygwin on a Remote Server

Tags: java, memory, cygwin, heap-memory, remote-server

I want to run a java program on **Cygwin**. The code takes two very large files as an input. When I attempted to run the program on Cygwin, I got the following messege:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at code_name.main(code_name.java:52)
```

I tried to increase the heapsize `(java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m javafile inputfile1  inputfile2)` but still it didn't work!

Does it solve the problem to run the code on a remote server with bigger memory? and if yes, how to define a server directory on Cygwin?

*Note that I'm using Windows, and my machine is 64-bit*

Comment: if something goes wrong it's not java fault, please attach your code so we can review it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not Java's fault that the application is using too much memory.  And it isn't Cygwin's fault either.

Most likely, it is one of the following:

- The application is using memory inefficiently; e.g. loading the files into memory in their entirety.
- The application has a memory leak
- The problem is inherently too big to solve with a 2GB heap.

---

> Does it solve the problem to run the code on a remote server with bigger memory?

Possibly yes, possibly no.  It depends on the reason that the application ran out of memory, and on the problem size.  It also depends on how much bigger the server is.

Hint: you should work out *why* the application is running out of memory with a 2GB heap.  There will be some clues in the application's source code, and in the stacktrace.

> And if yes, how to define a server directory on Cygwin?

I don't know what you mean by that.

I would suggest that you just login to the remote server, install cygwin, Java and the other tools that you need, and run the application from the remote server's command prompt.

Comment: My question is how to install cygwin on a remote server?

Comment: You need to have admin rights on the remote server.  Login to the remote server with admin rights ... and follow the Cygwin installation instructions.